# Prestashop 1.6: create payment method that redirects to payment gateway

Tags: prestashop, payment-gateway, prestashop-1.6

I am new to prestashop and just have a know-how about it. I want to develop a **payment method that redirects to the client's payment gateway**.

My client already has a payment method plugin for prestashop which shows embedded credit card form and calls APIs with these data to process the payment when order is placed.

I also want to place the order after the payment gateway redirects to my prestashop success URL else I have to retain the cart.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a module for your particular payment method. [Here](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/payment/) you can find documentation how to implement it.

Comment: I wish to implement on Prestashop 1.6 for now as lot of changes have been made in 1.7

Comment: Then, probably, this module can help you https://github.com/prestalab/universalpay. I didn't use it but the description says that it may be that what are you looking for. Or maybe this tutorial https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web_development/9781783280254/8